# Can I have "Automatic Breakpoints" when my code is reached?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging a quite complex C++ COM object in Visual Studio 2013 with what looks like stack corruption. I would like the debugger to stop whenever it reaches my own source code, is that possible?

Comment: Maybe just add logs?

Comment: I've never used it but maybe [DebugBreak()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx) will work for you.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: I've used it a couple of times before. It's not particularly nice or elegant, but it does the job.

Comment: Those who suggest putting breakpoints everywhere: how do you find all calls to COM objects so that you can be sure not to miss one?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the `COM` objects and are using `ATL` you can use `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_BREAK` to issue a break point every time a specific interface is queried for with `QueryInterface`.

This should allow you to break before any of your code has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a feature is enabled, but you could look into [Managed Debugging Assistants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), especially

- [gcManagedToUnmanaged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya4zeek2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),
- [gcUnmanagedToManaged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5b3680b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and
- [reportAvOnComRelease](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9180yaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This will make it more likely to detect problems closer to the origin.

Read about the other MDAs as well, especially if you have a suspect.